# can Mac Airport wifi be used for only certain devices I choose? HOW?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, airport

I have an aiport time capsule and I want to only allow my devices to "see" and use the wifi it puts out. The catch is I don't want other devices to even know my wifi is there. I'm at work and they don't want me to use my wifi, but theirs is unreliable and slow. In the past, when I had a password to my wifi, others found it and my wifi conflicted with the "corporate" wifi, and I had to shut mine down. I'm trying to avoid the "getting fired" part and just use my wifi for my devices, but not conflict with their wifi. Any suggestions? thanks!
I know how to set the access times, but I'm wondering if the "wireless clients" is what I need to set up, but I'm not sure how...

Comment: To avoid getting fired, i'd suggest not running it and getting on with your work instead.

You can setup hidden SSID's and such, but that won't stop a good sysadm finding you, nor the company firing you for disobeying direct orders.

Comment: Let it be seen & claim stupidity. Hide it & you've no defence.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "hide" a wireless network is to disable broadcasting the SSID, the network name. When the SSID is not broadcast, devices connecting to it must be told the name of the network they are to connect to.

**HOWEVER**, most devices will still show an "Unnamed wireless network" or "No SSID" label for the wireless network you're broadcasting, and your local friendly IT staff will not have any trouble finding the location of your illicit transmitter and finding you.

You can set a whitelist on certain routers allowing only specified devices to connect to the network, but that doesn't hide your network from other devices, it just prevents them from being joined to it.

So first, no, there is no way to completely hide a network. You're **broadcasting**, which really means "standing up someplace high and yelling", or something like that. You just can't hide it.

Second, your workplace is not about connecting personal devices for personal needs, and if your business wireless isn't good enough for business needs, that's a problem for your business to solve, not you.